# where to init another class in NSObject class?

Tags: iphone, init

alright, guys:

I met a problem during communicating between two classes,
the ViewControllerClass `MyViewController` calls a method `changeViewBackgroundColor` from a NSObjectClass `Assistant`

here is the method:

in `Assistant.h`

```
@interface Assistant : NSObject {

 MyViewControllere *myViewController;
```

in `Assistant.m`

```
- (void)changeViewBackgroundColor:(id)sender
{
    myViewController.myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

but i know this not gonna work, i need to `myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init]` the `myViewController`, the super class of `Assistant`, there is no place to implement it, if i implement in the `changeViewBackgroundColor` method, it be a little too late, there are several methods in this Assistant class, they all need `myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init]`, question is where i'm gonna put this `init` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override the init method and in init method create the object of myViewcontroller  . like

```
 -(void)init {
              if(self=[super init]){
                 //create the object for my view controller 
               }
   return self;      
}
```

i am still not sure for what purpose u using Assistant class....

Comment: "i am still not sure for what purpose u using Assistant class...." well, there are too many lines of code in MyViewControll class, hard to read, so put some methods apart, I'm trying your code:) but there is no init method originally in NSObject, just put into gonna work? I'm trying, response later

Comment: YES, its works! although some warnings in my scenario,   myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
  NSLog(@"alloced??: %@", myViewController ? @"myViewController" : @"NO");  returns YES, thank you very much! ^_^